# Algo to find nth compartment

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a large box say the BIG COMPARTMENT, this compartment is divided horizontally into multiple compartments of equal units.

**Details:**
1.The BIG compartment has its leftmost end on negative x axis and rightmost end on positive x axis so in between there are negative transforms.

**What we have:**
1. Number of compartments
2.starting X position of Big compartment
3.Ending X position of Big compartment
4.x position of an object placed on that BIG compartment

**What we want:**
The nth number of compartment on which the object is based on the position of object.

**Problem:**
Can not derive a formula that can handle position of object while on negative x to calculate the nth compartment .

What I guessed:

(width of compartment - position of object)/number of compartment

But this does not work at all with negatives

Comment: this seems like a) homework b) not programming. maybe show us what you have so far, and why you have a problem? what is harder about negative x?

Comment: It is a programming question, just asked in the simplest way possible.Updated question with what I had guessed but that's wrong and can not handle negatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `x_start`, `x_end`, `x_obj` and `n` denote starting X coordinate, ending X coordinate, X coordinate of object, and number of compartment repectively.

Then the compartment in which object falls = `[(x_obj - x_start)/(x_end - x_start)] * n`

This assumes that if `x_starts` falls on the shared edge of 2 compartments, than it goes into the left compartment